# How come my form input sometimes moves when I refresh the page?

Tags: html, css, forms

On a page that I'm designing I have a form with one input of type text. Normally, this form and input render properly in my browser, Chrome, but occasionally, it renders about 20 pixels to the left of where it is supposed to be. When I refresh the page, it goes back to the original, correct place.

I have only tested in Chrome so far, so this isn't a cross-browser issue (it happens in the same browser). Is there anything wrong with my code below?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE htmls>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<body >
<div id="supercontainer" class="style1">
    <img class="floater" src="top.jpg" alt="Top" />

        <img class="floater" src="left.jpg" alt="Left" />
        <div id="content">
            <p id="theText">
                Welcome. Please type a username.
            </p>

            <form id="prompt">
                <div><input type="text" name="promptLine" autocomplete="off" id="promptLine" onkeypress="return submitenter(event);" value="% " /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <img class="floater" src="right.jpg" alt="Right" />

    <img class="floater" src="bottom.jpg" alt="Bottom" />
</div>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
#supercontainer {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 900px;

display: block;
}

img.floater {
display: inline;
float: left;
}

#content {
background-color:black;
display: inline;
float: left;

padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
min-height:458px;
max-height:458px;
min-width: 803px;
max-width: 803px;

color: lime;
}

#theText {
text-align:left;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-top:0;

line-height: 0.3;

font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

#prompt {
position: fixed;
top: 470px;
}

#promptLine {
width: 100%;
background-color: black;

color: lime;

border: none;
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Check http://validator.w3.org and http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing your BODY and HTML tags? Also, doctype "htmls"?

Comment: Thats the doctype for HTML. I did close those tags, I just didn't copy it in above.

Comment: I've never heard of "htmls".  How are we to know the difference between a genuine error, and a 'just didn't copy it'?